# Why have I been banned from this account, my questions seem alright, and I even have 15 points. Is this a personal issue. who did this

Tags: discussion

I would like to know, who banned me from the account. I have not been rude or anything in my questions. Could this be a personal issue or something towards me.
I have 15 points. So, I don't understand, why I must be banned.

Answer (score 6):

> I would like to know, who banned me from the account.

The site itself did it, but it didn't ban you, it just stopped you asking new questions for a while on the main WP stack

> I have not been rude or anything in my questions. Could this be a personal issue or something towards me.

Nope, automation likely due to a combination flags/closed questions/low rep, the exact specifics/thresholds/reason are not shown to stop them gaming the system or reverse engineering it

> I have 15 points.

That's quite low, you want at least 200 to be considered "trustable" by the system. At that point it will auto-give you 100 reps on every other stack, which helps greatly to avoid automated moderation.

Note that having higher reputation is no guarantee it won't happen. The best way to avoid it is not to ask questions that get closed or flagged by other users.

---

I'd suggest waiting a while and avoiding future questions being closed, nothing stops you from answering and gaining reputation in other ways and it will help avoid the situation in the future

Comment: Thanks, I am just worried that I have to wait 6 months, before I can post another question.

Comment: FYI, you need 200 rep to get 100 rep on the other stacks. Also, 100 rep is not enough to keep you away from a question ban. I currently have one on a site where I have over 1100 rep (not including bounties I’ve made), and I’ve heard of far more extreme cases.

Comment: fixed the rep number